# Percentage diff between two strings of different lengths

Tags: string, algorithm, python-2.7, math

I have a problem where I am trying to prevent repeats of a string. So far the best solution is to compare the strings for a percentage and check if it is above a certain fixed point.

I've looked up Levenshtein distance but so far I believe it does not accomplish my goal since it compares strings of the same length. Both of my strings are more than likely to be significantly different lengths (stack trace). I'm looking for content or word comparison rather than char to char comparison. A percentage answer is the most important part of this.

Do I need an algorithm for this?

An indirect example... think of them as being stacktraces in py.test form. I have filepaths and am comparing them

```
/test/opt/somedir/blah/something  
def do_something(self, x):
    return x
SomeError: do_something in 'filepath' threw some exception or something
```

vs

```
/test/opt/somedir/blah2/somethingelse
def do_another_thing(self, y):
    return y
SomeError: do_another_thing in 'different filepath' threw some exception
```

But also when you have the same filepath, but different errors. The traces are hundreds of lines long, so showing a full example isn't reasonable. This example is as close as I can get without the actual trace.

Comment: What language? Many languages would allow you to simply loop through and compare word for word. If you have a specific word you can use regex on each string.

Comment: I am looking more for the algorithm. Python would be better though. I thought about that, but I'm not sure how that works with strings of different lengths, especially when it is a stack trace with filepaths and code (py.test output for multiple large tests).

Comment: Levenshtein is *not* restricted to strings of the same length.

Comment: Isn't it? or am I just being stupid... @Ami Tavory

Comment: You mention stack traces, can you explain more what kind of stack traces you want to compare, and what kind of result you want out of the comparison? If you have concrete examples of everything so much the better.

Comment: @Ian You're not being stupid, but it includes insert and erase ops, so it's not restricted to equal lengths. Incidentally, I must say I do not understand your question at all. You might consider adding a short example.

Comment: Updated with example

Comment: Longest Common Substring (or Subsequence) might give you some information.

Comment: @Ian FYI, if you want someone specific to see a comment (and assuming that's the case here), you need to add a "@" + name thingy somewhere in the comment.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen , thank you for your input. LCS looks promising. I'll try my hand at implementing it and see if it I can fiddle with it to make it work for me. Thank you all. Not answered as of yet though, just a good lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of going at this would be through applications of the [Jaro-Winkler String Similarity metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance). Happily, this has a [PyPI package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jaro_winkler/1.0.2).

Let's start off with three string, your two examples, and the begining of your question:

```
s1 = u'''
/test/opt/somedir/blah/something  
def do_something(self, x):
    return x
SomeError: do_something in 'filepath' threw some exception or something'''

s2 = u'''
/test/opt/somedir/blah2/somethingelse
def do_another_thing(self, y):
    return y
SomeError: do_another_thing in 'different filepath' threw some exception'''

q = u'''
I have a problem where I am trying to prevent repeats of a string. So far the best solution is to compare the strings for a percentage and check if it is above a certain fixed point.'''
```

Then the similarities are:

```
>> jaro.jaro_metric(s1, s2)
0.8059572665529058

>> jaro.jaro_metric(s1, q)
0.6562121541167517
```

---

However, since you know something of the problem domain (it is a sequence of lines of stacktraces), you could do better by calculating line differences, perhaps:

```
import itertools

>> [jaro.jaro_metric(l1, l2) for l1, l2 in itertools.izip(s1.split('\n'), s2.split('\n'))]
[1.0,
 0.9353471118177001,
 0.8402824228911184,
 0.9444444444444443,
 0.8043725314852076]
```

So, you need to experiment with this, but you could try, given two stacktraces, calculating a "distance" which is a matrix - the i-j entry would be the similarity between the i-th string of the first to the j-th of the second. (This is a bit computationally expensive.) See if there's a threshold for a percentage or number of entries obtaining very high scores.

Comment: Thank you @Ami . Very helpful. I'll probably be utilizing the application with the strings (since my example was wrong, I might have an extra line or two). But this fulfills my needs almost perfectly. I'll get back to you after trying it, but thank you!